# Delete Symlink from ~/Desktop

Tags: desktop, symlink

A while ago I deleted my `~/Desktop` directory and then (using a symlink) pointed it to another directory (a subdirectory of my Google Drive directory). No, that my setup has changed, I would like to remove the symlink and have a proper `~/Desktop` directory again. The following did not work:

```
rm -rf ~/Desktop
sudo rm -rf ~/Desktop
unlink
```

They all return this error message:

```
rm: Desktop: Operation not permitted
```

I even fail pointing the symlink to another location using  `sudo ln -sf ./Desktop2 Desktop`.

How can I get my Desktop back? (i.e. delete the symlink and create a desktop folder).

Calling `ls -l@Oed Desktop` leads to the following output:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 my-user-name staff  schg 52 22 Jul  2020 Desktop -> /Users/my-user-name/some-existing-path/
```

Calling `sudo chflags noschg ~/Desktop` did not lead to any change with this:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 my-user-name staff  schg 52 22 Jul  2020 Desktop -> /Users/my-user-name/some-existing-path/
```

Comment: Can you please include the output of `ls -l@Oed Desktop` in your question?

Comment: Thanks, Tink! I added this to the question :-)

Comment: for me: ls -l@Oed Desktop drwx------+ 37 my_username staff - 1184 Apr 11 10:18 Desktop 0: group:everyone deny delete So I am am surprised you could delete the Desktop to start with (it would be useful to know how you deleted it to start with).

Comment: That `schg` flag means it's locked against changes (including deletion) by the superuser. You can try `sudo chflags noschg ~/Desktop`, but it may not work -- schg is not supposed to be removable except in single-user mode. BTW, I'd also avoid using the `-r` flag with `rm`, since that means to delete the contents (of a directory), and in this case you just want to delete the symlink, not the contents of the directory it's pointing to.

Comment: Verify what you have in Finder > Preferences > Sidebar - it should be there, may need to be checked. I had once a similar problem and solved there. Just try it.

Comment: Thanks, Gordon! Using chflags did not produce any results. Unfortunately, I do not have the slightest idea how I managed to delete the folder in the first place (I did it about three years ago and do not remember anything out of the ordinary - so maybe earlier Mac OS X versions were less rigid in protecting the ~/Desktop folder?)

Comment: Thanks, Yoan. I checked and unchecked the option mutliple times but it did not produce any result (other then creating multiple short cuts in the left sidebar).

Comment: Try `sudo chflags -h ...` to change the permissions on the symlink itself.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you so much, hohillside! Woud you like to add this as a proper answer? I am happy to upvote and mark as correct - so that you get some points out ouf it :-)